# Runtime error "wrong name: applicationarbre / Main"

Tags: java

I add the path of jdk in the environment variable "path", my position is on the directory of the application: "C:\Users\20900994t\Desktop\applicationArbre_2_1\src\applicationarbre" 
I have 4 .java files .

I tried 2 methodes.

The first method were: 
1. "javac Main.java" 2. "java Main"

The second method were: 
1. "javac *. java" 2. "java Main.java"

These methods generate all of the files . classes of all the classes I have, but at the command line it shows me that the purpose of the other classes are not recognized and when I did "java Main", it shows me "NoClasseDefFoundError"

Actually, those method works well in environment Net Beans, however I need to execute it on command line with .bat file .
 Thank's

Comment: What command are you typing on the command line?

Comment: javac Main.java   then java Main

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're running it like this:

```
// In directory applicationarbre
$ java Main
```

You should be running it like this, in the *parent* directory:

```
$ java applicationarbe.Main
```

You say you've tried several solutions, but you haven't explained what you've tried, or what happened when you tried them, which makes it hard to help you further.

Basically, you need to tell Java the fully-qualified name of the class you want to launch, and that class has to be available on the classpath, which is "the current directory" by default. Anything more than that and you'll need to give us more information.

Comment: @kaouthar: It's hard to read all this information in comments - it should be in your question. Then please read the documentation for the javac and java tools.

Answer (score 1):

Not like this:

```
java applicationarbre/Main
```

but like this:

```
java applicationarbre.Main
```

As for the classpath, maybe in your case this will be enough (if you are in the correct base directory below which are your classfiles):

```
java -cp . applicationarbre.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

first compile the class in which main method resides

C:\foldername>javac ClassName.java

then run with statement

C:\foldername>java ClassName

hope it will work :)